# FIWARE Lab, access to wirecloud log

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud, filab

How can I read information from FI-LAB WireCloud log?

I can read information from widgets logs, but how can I debug information from an operator?

Is there an way to detect if operator can't connect to source?

Comment: are you developing an source operator? or are you using any of the source operators provided in FIWARE Lab?

Comment: I'm using CoNWeT NGSI Source Widget 3.0. I't Looks that it doesn't send information to log in case there is a error getting a connection to source.

Comment: Version 3.0.2 (not yet released) of the NGSI Source operator will improve this, stay tuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, WireCloud displays an error icon when an operator logs an error message:

[image: Operator displaying an alert icon]

You can click on the alert icon for accessing log information. Also those errors should be displayed on the workspace view:

[image: Wiring icon displaying an error badget]

Currently WireCloud is missing an option for accessing those logs if the operator doesn't log any error. I've created a [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/38) in the [WireCloud's issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues) for adding such an option.

> **Note:** The ticket was closed and now it is possible to access the logs without having to wait for an error.